# Show notification only on phone (not on Android Wear)

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os, android-wear-notification

Is there any way to prevent a notification be shown on Android Wear device? I know it's possible by using `setOngoing(true)` but I don't want my notification to be ongoing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should call `setLocalOnly(true)` on the `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

From the documentation

> Set whether or not this notification should not bridge to other
>   devices.

you can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLocalOnly(boolean))